# Separate hand from forearm using contours

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, openframeworks

I'm working on an installation where visitors hold their arms over a table (with a map projection) and additional information is projected onto their hands. So far I have a robust method of detecting the arms and hands extended over the table, and have a vector representing the contour of these blobs. Since this needs to work quickly and with many hands at once, I don't want to do actual hand detection.

However, I do need to separate the hand from the forearm, in order to project the new information in the correct place. My current idea is to find the point at which the blob leaves the frame, assume that is the forearm, and perform a linear fit to the data points (because forearms are pretty much straight). When the contour departs from this line, I'll assume it's the wrist. Do it on the other side, divide the blob by these points, and voila, I'll have the hand.

Does this make sense? Am I missing something obvious? I'm using ofxOpenCv, so I'm working with pretty limited functionality. I'm just looking for the quickest/easiest way to do this.

Comment: I did something similar once with Processing, and I ended up writing a class that took a custom polygon that was shaped to trim out parts of the arm and returned a new image that i then passed to a blob detection routine... maybe something along that route ?

Comment: Sounds interesting! How did you trim out the arm?

Comment: basically i knew that the hand would always be at a certain part of the image because of the physical constraints of the installation, so i made a series of polygons that would only capture that region of interest...